Karate - Getting error "com.intuit.karate - org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to <DOMAIN>:443"
Currently I experiencing an error
com.intuit.karate - org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to <DOMAIN>:443 [] failed: Connection timed out: no further information, http call failed after 21072 milliseconds for url: <URL>
WARN  com.intuit.karate - retry condition evaluation failed: http call failed after 21072 milliseconds for url: <URL>

Even though I have added configure readTimeout = 120000 in the feature as well as in the karate-config.js. Below is from the karate-config.js
karate.configure('retry',{ count:5, interval:6000});
karate.configure('connectTimeout', 120000);
karate.configure('readTimeout', 120000);
karate.configure('ssl', true);
karate.configure('logPrettyRequest', true);

Ps: This is working fine in the Postman without any issues and that too several times I attempted to hit the API call, it's working.

I tried to upgrade the karate-core from 1.4.0 to 1.4.1 but it didn't work.
I tried to increase the readTimeout in the feature as well as in the karate-config.json but this also didn't work.
I tried to hit the same API call in Postman, and there it's working fine (With multiple attempts).

